# not SSL addresses in PWA?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am stuck in my PWA application as I need to access informations from a non-SSL url (http). I know that PWA has a strict requirement on this. Is there any workaround or do I simply have to give up?

Comment: Sorry, what is PWA? The tag you used doesn't seem to be related in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can host your PWAs in Firebase.  They provision it with SSL certs.  Then you can connect your domain to your firebase app.  Do not give up just yet.:) there is always a way

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the problem is not the host. The application is hosted on a remote server with certs and SSL. But inside the application I need to access informations from a non-SSL server...

Comment: I dont think that you can access data/information between 2 sites that are is not both of the same protocol.  How are you accessing the data?  Through ajax?

Comment: ITs a bit confusing.  You mentioned "access", so are you getting information from a non-SSL site?  But you also mentioned <form> which means you are sending information to the SSL site.  Which one is it?

And by the way...did you try it?

Comment: Currently, my webapp sends the form data to the non-SSL site and displays results from it in an iframe. So, yes, I am sending and receving data from it.

Comment: The page at 'https//.....' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint

Comment: Theoretically, it sounds that is should work.  If your main PWA sits behind an SSL and you are following the PWA checklist, it should work

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. This is the message shown in the console: The page at 'https//.....' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint

Comment: Then like i mentioned earlier, if the 2 sites/sources are of different protocols, there isn't much that you can do to by pass it.  If you want a PWA, put it behind a SSL.

Comment: Thank you. My first impression (to give up with this application) was right!

Comment: Why dont you provision an SSL for the other one?